# Viewport strangeness across a few devices - Any reliable way to show 100% width on initial entry regardless of os + orientation?

Tags: android, ios, landscape, viewport, portrait

We have the following viewport meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1024, initial-scale=1.0"/>
```

Here is a breakdown of what happens upon site entry:

iPad + iOS 6.0 + Landscape = correct

ipad + iOS 6.0 + Portrait = same 'zoom level' as landscape, so about 65% of the width is shown, the rest needs to be scrolled.

Android 4.0 Galaxy S3 + Built in browser + Landscape = Zoomed in real close, about 60% of the width is shown, rest needs to be scrolled.

Android 4.0 Galaxy S3 + Built in browser + Portrait = Zoomed in real close, about 60% of the width is shown, rest needs to be scrolled.

Android 4.0 Galaxy S3 + Chrome (play store downloaded) browser + Landscape = Zoomed in even closer, only about 45% of the width is initially shown.

Android 4.0 Galaxy S3 + Chrome (play store downloaded) browser + Portrait = Zoomed in even closer, only about 50% of the width is initially shown.

Android 4.0 Tab 10.1 + Landscape = correct

Android 4.0 Tab 10.1 + Portrait = same zoom level as landscape, so the effect is nearly identical to ipad + portrait.

Is there any cross browser reliable way to have the page show 100% of the width regardless of orientation / ios / android?

Am I correct in assuming that regardless of all of the above, mobile devices tend to 'remember' the zoom level on a per domain level?

Are we using the viewport meta tag incorrectly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is that for any kind of page with Javascript content, you cannot guarantee how it will look. The browsers have different Javascript engines, support different tags, etc.

Answer (score 0):

We found that by removing the `viewport` meta tag completely, all of the above cases began displaying correctly... at 100% width upon initial entry.